I need to fix this formula so that the columns letters go UP as I drag DOWN
So specifically with the following formula, how do i fix make the range say =B2:b21, =C2:c21. =D2:d21, etc when i drag down?
The full formula is:
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER('Staff Rota'!$A$2:$A$21,('Staff Rota'!B2:B21="W")*('Staff Rota'!B2=D2)))

Lookup table

Bookings table

Really appreciate some guidance on this.
I have tried so match with index match etc but to no avail

Try using the following formula:


=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER($A$4:$A$10,FILTER($B$4:$E$10,G2=$B$2:$E$2,"")="W",""))


Or, Can use XLOOKUP() + FILTER()
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER($A$4:$A$10,XLOOKUP(G2,$B$2:$E$2,$B$4:$E$10,"")="W",""))


Or, can spill the whole range using a LAMBDA() helper function called MAP()
=MAP(G2:G11,LAMBDA(α, 
 TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(A4:A10,
 FILTER(B4:E10,B2:E2=α,"")="W",""))))


And also, since you have mentioned that tried using INDEX()+MATCH() but no avail then here is using INDEX()+MATCH() <-- This will be same with CHOOSECOL()+XMATCH()
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(A$4:A$10,IFNA(INDEX(B$4:E$10,,MATCH(G2,B$2:E$2,0)),"")="W",""))


You will need to change the range and references as per your suit!

You, sir, are an absolute genius! I thought I was OK with spreadhseets and formulas. But you have shown me that there are levels to this game. And you are miles and miles ahead. Wish you all the best, and thank you so much.

Why don't we ditch the helper column alltogether:

Formula in G3:
=HSTACK(TRANSPOSE(B2:E3),BYROW(TRANSPOSE(REPT(A4:A10,B4:E10="W")),LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN(", ",,r))))


Hi JvdV. That also seems like a proper, and dare i say it, neater solution. Howeever when i try it, i get an error message. Can't seem to past it here for some reason.

I read in the comments you have excel 2021.... That's why. :) @AbsRa
